# Datatables Jquery Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex')

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I know this has been asked a lot but I really cannot find my error on this one. I've been doing a lot of changes but still cannot figure out what's wrong. `<th>` and `<td>` matched number, I tried removing colspans too but had no luck. Any advice? By the way, here is my code please have a look.

```
    window.load_tbl = function(){
            var val = document.getElementById('assignval').value;
          
            $('#faculty-tbl tbody').html('<tr><td colspan="6" class="text-center">Please Wait...</td></tr>')
            $.ajax({
                url:'functions/'+val,
                success:function(resp){
                    if(typeof resp != undefined){
                        resp = JSON.parse(resp)
                        if(Object.keys(resp).length > 0){
                            $('#faculty-tbl tbody').html('')
                            var i = 1;
                            Object.keys(resp).map(k=>{
                                var date_updated = moment(resp[k].date_updated).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a');
                                var tr = $('<tr></tr>')
                                tr.append('<td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">'+resp[k].id+'</button></td>')
                                tr.append('<td class="text-center">'+resp[k].firstname+'</td>')
                                tr.append('<td class="text-center">'+resp[k].middlename+'</td>')
                                tr.append('<td class="text-center">'+resp[k].lastname+'</td>')
                                if(resp[k].section_id != 0) {
                                 tr.append('<td class="text-center">'+resp[k].advisory+'</td>')   
                                } else {
                                 tr.append('<td class="text-center">Unassigned</td>')
                                }
                                tr.append('<td><center><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm text-white edit_faculty" data-id = "'+resp[k].id+'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove_faculty" data-id = "'+resp[k].id+'" data-firstname="'+resp[k].firstname+'" data-middlename="'+resp[k].middlename+'" data-lastname="'+resp[k].lastname+'" data-uid="'+resp[k].user_id+'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button><button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm text-white show_date" data-date = "'+date_updated+'"><i class="fa-solid fa-database"></i></button></center></td>')
                                $('#faculty-tbl tbody').append(tr)
                            })
                        }else{
                        $('#faculty-tbl tbody').html('<tr><td colspan="6" class="text-center">No Data...</td></tr>')
                        }
                    }
                },
                complete:function(){
                    $('#faculty-tbl').dataTable()
                }
            })
        }

        $(document).on('change', '.assigned', function() {
            if(this.checked) {
            document.getElementById('assignval').value = 'load_ajax.php?action=load_faculty';
            load_tbl();
            } else {
            document.getElementById('assignval').value = 'filter_ajax.php?action=filter_unassignedfaculty';
            load_tbl();
            }
        });
    
        $('#new_faculty').click(function(){
            uni_modal('Add faculty','functions/manage_faculty.php');
        })

        $(document).ready(function() {
            
            load_tbl()
            
            $('#faculty-tbl tbody').on('click', '.edit_faculty', function () {
                uni_modal("Update Faculty Information",'functions/manage_faculty.php?id='+$(this).attr('data-id'))
            });
            
            $('.help').on('click', function () {
                help_modal("Need Help?")
            });
            
            $('#faculty-tbl tbody').on('click', '.remove_faculty', function () {
                window.uid = $(this).attr('data-uid');
                window.firstname = $(this).attr('data-firstname');
                window.middlename = $(this).attr('data-middlename');
                window.lastname = $(this).attr('data-lastname');
                _conf("Are you sure to remove this data?",'remove_faculty', [$(this).attr('data-id')])
            });
            
            $('#faculty-tbl tbody').on('click', '.show_date', function () {
            static_modal("Faculty Information", "Last Date Updated: "+$(this).attr('data-date'))
            });
            
            $('#print_faculty').click(function(){
            var redirectWindow = window.open('print/report_faculty.php');
            redirectWindow.location;
            
            });
            
            $('#reloadBtn').click(function(){
            location.reload();
            });
            
            var table = $('#users-tbl')
            if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#users-tbl')) {
               return;
            }
            else {
                var table = $('#users-tbl').DataTable();
                table.dataTable().fnDestroy();
            }
        
        });
```

If I miss anything also let me know, I'm doing an Enrollment System atm.

I've tried multiple things like matching rows and columns, and also did a few code that is recommended by the others but still no luck. I have no trouble loading the data but I just want this error gone and never thrown in the first place.

Comment: What has been asked a lot?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. I've been ignoring the simplest mistake ever, I keep putting a default  message when there is no data available in the table which is clearly not supported by the data table, and when I removed it all my problems went away.

Considered this fixed.

Edit: As said by anrdewJames, I'll expand my answer for anyone who *also encounters this error.*

In my code there are two  with colspans which in my case:

```
$('#faculty-tbl tbody').html('<tr><td colspan="6" class="text-center">Please Wait...</td></tr>')
$('#faculty-tbl tbody').html('<tr><td colspan="6" class="text-center">No Data...</td></tr>')
```

I completely removed the first line because I run this code when the data is still loading. Here's my solution:

The first error changed into:

```
window.check_tbl = function() {
var table = $('#faculty-tbl').DataTable();
   if ( ! table.data().any() ) {
        $('#faculty-tbl').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    }   
}
```

The second error, if the table has no data simply clear and draw.

```
var table = $('#faculty-tbl').DataTable();
table.clear()
.draw();
```

In any case, don't try to be so fancy as Datatable has default messages.

Comment: I added the changes I made in my code @andrewJames thanks for the heads up!